# Android add variable to Database Query

Tags: java, android, database

I have this piece of code that does not work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    String option = names.getText().toString();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from numbers Where fname=option", null);
```

Comment: "SELECT * from numbers Where fname="+option

Answer (score 1):

Change as below :

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from numbers Where fname='"+option+"' ", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String query = "SELECT * from numbers Where fname='"+ option +"'";      
    database.execSQL(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefer using a Prepared Statement with `?` place holders.

```
String option = names.getText().toString();
String query = "SELECT * from numbers Where fname = ?"

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {option});
```